# Stop VB.net changing inputs like 01 to just 1?

Tags: vb.net

i'm struggling to find a solution to this. I am currently trying to take an input like 01 and keep it that way through the program, however VB.net seems to format that down to just 1. Is there any way to stop it doing this?

Thank you in advance, i'm sorry if this is just my stupidity.

Comment: Well you should show the code that makes this magic. I have a suspicion

Comment: @Steve, let me think, input is a string stored in a int then doing tostring on the int? :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it as "01" , you should store it in a string format not integer or any numerical data type. If you must use integers , you can display the output only in the format you want like this :

```
Dim int As Integer = 1
Console.Writeline(Format(int, "00"))
```

This should give you the output in the desired format. I hope that was helpful for you.